# Monotouch UITableView delete row

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xamarin.ios

Hey - I have the following method on my     UITableView controller

```
public void RemoveEventFromList(Event evt){

            if (_sessions != null) {

                if (_sessions.Contains(evt)) {

                    _sessions.Remove(evt);

                }
            }

            this.tableView.ReloadData();
        }
```

which doesn't do anything!! - how do i manually remove the item from the list? this method is called from the next view in the nav tree (the details view) - so there is no selected row or anything like that.

this is the only thing holding me back from submitting the free version of my app to the appstore! so aaaaaaaany help really appreciated!

:)

w://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the data on the tableView before reloading.  This usually involves reinitializing the DataSource property with, in your case, the updated _sessions collection.  Try that out.

Comment: i ended up just [dirty] re-init everything in the tab on the viewdidappear event - not good - i havent submitted it yet so i'll try your method first :)